# SQL Query to find distinct records and Update a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table ABC which has following records -

```
  INVC_NUM    | LINE_NUMBER  |  ORGANIZATION_ID  | STATUS    |  DATE

  0000034454       1             521                 Validated   09/09/2016 

  0000034454       2             521                 Validated    04/09/2016 

  0000034410       1             521                 Validated    04/09/2016

  0000034410       2             521                 notValidated    04/09/2016

  0000034410       3             521                 notValidated   04/09/2016

  0000034410       4             521                 Validated   04/09/2016
```

Now I need to update a table XYZ which has following columns

```
INVC_NUM     |   ORGANIZATION_ID   | date

0000034454   |   521               | 09/09/2016    
0000034410   |   521               | null
```

Whenever the status for all the Line_number's for particular INVC_NUM and organization_id are "ALL" validated(status)then we need to update XYZ with sysdate.

Whenever the status for all the Line_number's for particular INVC_NUM and organization_id are NOT ALL of them validated(Status) then we need to update XYZ with NULL. XYZ has unique record for each INVC_NUM and Org_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know whether *all* statuses for an INVC_NUM and organization_id are valid, see if you find an invalid one:

```
update xyz
set date =
case when not exists
  (
    select *
    from abc
    where abc.invc_num = xyz.invc_num
      and abc.organization_id = xyz.organization_id
      and abc.status = 'notValidated'
  ) then sysdate 
end;
```

(Omitting the `ELSE` branch defaults to null, which is what we want. If you consider it more readable, change `then sysdate end` to `then sysdate else null end`.)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. I have a small change in the requirement. If I want to take the max(date) coming from another column and update that date instead of using sysdate, how can I achieve that?

Comment: I'd say replace `sysdate` in above query with `(select max(datecolumnname) from tablename)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  It uses aggregation to return one row:

```
update xyz
    set date = (select (case when count(*) = 0 then sysdate end)
                from abc
                where abc.status = 'NotValidated' and
                      abc.invc_num = xyz.invc_num and
                      abc.organization_id = xyz.organization_id
               );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Do I need to use Organization_id too in the where clause?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Is there any sql query in the world that you can solve. Bow down to GOD of SQL.

Comment: @beckham Yes. You must use Organization_id too in the where clause.

Comment: @beckham . . . Maybe.  If a single invoice can be in multiple organizations, then you need to include it.

Comment: I don't get it. Shoudn't we count **'notValidated'** records, so as to see whether *all* records are validated or not?

Comment: Okay, from the comments it sounded as if the query was working, which had me wondering. Now change `>` to `=` and that should be it :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . It is checking that there are zero "notValidated".

Comment: ... and in case there are zero 'notValidated' we want to update with sysdate. But you are updating with sysdate in the opposite case.

Comment: Thanks Gordon and Thorsten. I have small change in the requirement and I have updated my question. Would you be able to help me out? I tried pass MAX(DATE) instead of sysdate in your queries and its updating with null values.